# Migrate files and metadata

Tags: metadata, document-migration

I want to copy all the documents from file system into sharepoint document library along with all the metadata in excel. For example there are two documents in file system named "A" and "B", and there is an excel file in which the documents name are defined A and B and then there are others columns as well such as Document Type, Document ID, etc. So i want to copy the document into document library along with the metadata of that document which is defined in excel file. So is there any tool, through which we can achieve this?

Thanks!